# Modifying a PHP collection

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, collections

For a wordpress website I'm developing, I'm making a dynamic menu that users can make using the admin menu. Hooking into that is only the least of my problems.

The code I'm using returns these arrays:

```
                        Array
(
    [0] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 35
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_date] => 2013-05-19 15:46:22
            [post_date_gmt] => 2013-05-19 15:46:22
            [post_content] =>  
            [post_title] => 
            [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => publish
            [comment_status] => open
            [ping_status] => open
            [post_password] => 
            [post_name] => 35
            [to_ping] => 
            [pinged] => 
            [post_modified] => 2013-05-19 16:07:09
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2013-05-19 16:07:09
            [post_content_filtered] => 
            [post_parent] => 0
            [guid] => http://adapt.local/?p=35
            [menu_order] => 1
            [post_type] => nav_menu_item
            [post_mime_type] => 
            [comment_count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
            [db_id] => 35
            [menu_item_parent] => 0
            [object_id] => 32
            [object] => training
            [type] => post_type
            [type_label] => Training
            [url] => http://adapt.local/training/alcohol/
            [title] => Alcohol
            [target] => 
            [attr_title] => 
            [description] => 
            [classes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                )

            [xfn] => 
        )

    [1] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 36
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_date] => 2013-05-19 16:07:09
            [post_date_gmt] => 2013-05-19 16:07:09
            [post_content] =>  
            [post_title] => 
            [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => publish
            [comment_status] => open
            [ping_status] => open
            [post_password] => 
            [post_name] => 36
            [to_ping] => 
            [pinged] => 
            [post_modified] => 2013-05-19 16:07:09
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2013-05-19 16:07:09
            [post_content_filtered] => 
            [post_parent] => 0
            [guid] => http://adapt.local/?p=36
            [menu_order] => 2
            [post_type] => nav_menu_item
            [post_mime_type] => 
            [comment_count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
            [db_id] => 36
            [menu_item_parent] => 35
            [object_id] => 32
            [object] => training
            [type] => post_type
            [type_label] => Training
            [url] => http://adapt.local/training/alcohol/
            [title] => Alcohol
            [target] => 
            [attr_title] => 
            [description] => 
            [classes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                )

            [xfn] => 
        )

)
```

To explain: if menu_item_parent = 0, that means it is a top-node, and if menu_item_parent > 0, it means it is a 'subnode'.

I want to convert this horrible array to something more useful, preferably something like this

```
Array
(
    [35] => Array
    (
        name => "Topnode"
        url => "http://topnodeurl"
        items => Array
        (
            name => "Subnode"
            url => "http://subnodeurl"
        )
    )
)
```

I thought: Hey, this couldn't be that hard. But, apparently, this doesn't seem to work:

```
foreach($menuitems as $menuitem) {
    if(!$menuitem->menu_item_parent) {
        $items[$menuitem->ID] = array("name" => $menuitem->title,"items" => array());
        #print_r($items);
    }
    else {
        $parent = $items[$menuitem->menu_item_parent]['items'];
        $parent = array("name" => $menuitem->title, "url" => $menuitem->url);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a recursive function

```
function make_menu($items, $parent_id = 0)
{
    $menu = [];
    foreach($items as $key => $item) {
        if (item['menu_item_parent'] == $parent_id ) {
            $item['childs'] = make_menu($items, $item['ID']);
            $menu[] = $item;

            // Helps speed up the foreach by removing items that are not needed any more
            unset($item[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $menu;
}
```

This way you can have a deeper function then just 1 layer

Comment: How would this work? I don't believe $items['childs'] would do something since the recursive function isn't returning anything?

Comment: Sorry my bad forgot to return menu

Comment: Perfect! This seems to do the job. I shouldn't worry about all the 'extra data' now. This just does everything.